# BackBone model ToJSON renders a field to zero

Tags: javascript, json, model, backbone.js

I have some strange behavior in my model. When I was debugging with this code something strange emerged:

```
console.log(this.model);
console.log(this.model.toJSON());
```

These 2 lines offer two different results. The log of *this.model*

```
attributes: Object
   distance: "6500"
   duration: "25:17.1"
   id: "33"
   intervalid: "1"
   pace: "1:56.7"
   rowdate: "2012-03-08 20:47:36"
   trainingid: "18"
```

And then the log of the *toJSON()*

```
Object
   distance: "6500"
   duration: "0"
   id: "33"
   intervalid: "1"
   pace: "1:56.7"
   rowdate: "2012-03-08 20:47:36"
   trainingid: "18"
```

Does anybody have a clue why my **duration** field is reduced to 0? And a way to prevent **toJSON()** from changing **duration** to 0?

Comment: Is your backbone and underscore libraries are up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, even when I set `duration: String("25:17.1")`:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4eeU/

Model.toJSON source:

```
toJSON: function() {
  return _.clone(this.attributes);
},
```

Underscore source:

```
// Create a (shallow-cloned) duplicate of an object.
_.clone = function(obj) {
  if (!_.isObject(obj)) return obj;
  return _.isArray(obj) ? obj.slice() : _.extend({}, obj);
};
```

Comment: I found the bug. Somewhere another piece of code was rewriting the model :doh: